# meaning of the adjective "singular" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/HQPA5oNpfM4). It is at 55 second. Here it goes:

> The first European visitors to the Americas had never seen a tomato or a catfish; native americans had never seen a horse, and by making our planet biologically **singular**, the Columbian exchange completely remade the population of animals, particularly humans.

I cannot get from the context whether the presenter meant biologically very good or biologically less diverse.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wels_catfish

Comment: "Dr. Ross MacPhee, Curator of Mammalogy at the American Museum of Natural History, and colleagues, have dated the existence of woolly mammoths and horses in North America to as recent as 7,600 years ago. Had it not been for previous westward migration, over the 2 Bering Land Bridge, into northwestern Russia (Siberia) and Asia, the horse would have faced complete extinction. However, Equus survived and spread to all continents of the globe, except Australia and Antarctica." https://awionline.org/content/wild-horses-native-north-american-wildlife

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singular, from *single* "One in number".

The human world before 1492 was divided into two parts: One with Tomatoes and Catfish, the other with Horses.

After 1492 the human world became one part. The presenter doesn't say if this was good or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume from the context that "singular" here means "united" or probably even "one", like in "two become one".

The idea here lies in merging two separates into a whole.